# How to use custom role-based authorization with Windows authentication in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, role-base-authorization

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC3 intranet application with **Windows authentication**. I only want domain users to use this application. Once a domain user is authenticated (with **Active Directory**), I'm planning to create Users (with AD username), Roles & UserRoles tables in SQL Server for **authorization**.

So if an user is a part of a role which has some set of permissions (to access controllers/actions), I should only allow the users in that role to execute/view them.

Eg: if there is an action /Locations/Create, the roles which are allowed to perform that, can only do that.

Can somebody give me some pointers? Should I create a custom action filter, and use filter attribute to any action method that I want the filter to apply to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To restrict access to an ASP.NET MVC view, you restrict access to the
>   action method that renders the view. To accomplish this, the MVC
>   framework provides the AuthorizeAttribute class.

Example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
{
 return View();
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) for more details.

Note that using the [Authorize] attribute requires you to use some sort of Membership provider.

Comment: Thanks @autonomatt. Since I prefer using our own table structure for Users/Roles in SQL Server rather than ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile, should I implement a custom membership provider? Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article a good way to proceed?

Comment: That's what I did. When researching I came across lots of posts that say the same thing. Using MS's table structure is not recommened. Mainly because of the way it stores certain data, which makes it very hard to query. I use NHibernate in my data access layer and have built a custom NHibernate Membership Provider. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55174/Custom-Fluent-Nhibernate-Membership-and-Role-Provi) helped me. And [this article by Mauricio Scheffer](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html) is somewhat related if you want to use IoC.